# Why is the glass transparency not consistent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

I followed Blenderguru's tutorial and made some gum drops. Then I made glass container and use rigid body to fill it with dozens of gums, but why does it look so strange from outside? It looks like there are only three or four, or as if the glass is 10 inches thick...

The gums are not intersecting with the glass either. How can I make it look more realistic?
[image: Why is the gum inside the glass like this?]

[image: The Settings]

The file: [image]

Comment: Hello :). Keep in mind those colored spots are reflections of your foreground gumdrops, not the actual gumdrops inside the jar.

Comment: Ohhhh you're right! >< I should now change the question to why does the glass not that transparent at all....how come things inside are grey...

Answer (score 1):

ok, i deleted some planes you created (i have no idea what they did) and i changed your cylinder material to this:

[image]

result was (after i added a ground plane with some color)

[image]

and here is my changed blend file to check out:

[image]